# Trying to validate the background property of an object when it is in the CSS style

Tags: ruby, coding-style, background, nomethoderror

- Ruby version 1.9.2
- gem version 1.8.1
- IE version 8 in compatibility mode

I have an object on the page (is actually a cell in a table) that is defined as a "TD class=burst>100<" in the DOM (HTML).
There is a CSS attached as well with several style properties for that object (e.g. color, text-align).
The CSS style code looks like the following:

```
 DIV.points TD.burst 
    text-align : center
    width : 55px
      ...
    background : url(xxxx.png) no-repeat 50% 0px
    color : #fff
      ...
```

The style background property of the object is displaying an image on the page.

I am trying to validate that the correct image is being displayed using watir, so I am trying to retrieve the background property:

```
 image_id = $ie.cell(:class=>"burst",:index=>1).style.background
```

I am getting a method_missing': unknown property or method: `background' (NoMethodError) error.

I am able to get other properties like:

```
 image_id = $ie.cell(:class=>"burst",:index=>1).style.width
 image_id = $ie.cell(:class=>"burst",:index=>1).style.color
```

The same results occur for `currentstyle`.

Does anyone know a way I would be able to access the background property/method of the object when it is in the CSS style?

Comment: Are you sure this question is about Ruby? What are you programming in?

Comment: The application that I am testing against is not written in Ruby.  I am creating test automation using Ruby and Watir.  I am trying to get the background property/method values while running Ruby/Watir.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the information I needed by using the backgroundimage property instead of the background property (since the background property is made up of several properties including the backgroundimage property).